# How to insert Product Images using Salesforce OCAPI 19.1?

Tags: java, api, salesforce, commerce

I am trying to insert a new product from my app into my Salesforce Commerce (Sandbox). When I use the Data API 19.3 Put /products, it is inserting but not the images.

This is the format of the json that I am using (please see below). Let me know if I missed out or something. Thanks!

```
    "image": {
  "path": "large/6288348_sd.jpg",
  "alt": "Samsung - 50\" Class - LED - NU6900 Series - 2160p - Smart - 4K UHD TV with HDR, , hi-res",
  "abs_url": "<my image location in site>",
  "dis_base_url": "<my image location in site>",
  "title": "Samsung - 50\" Class - LED - NU6900 Series - 2160p - Smart - 4K UHD TV with HDR, "
 },
 "image_groups": [
  {
   "images": [{
    "path": "large/6288348_sd.jpg",
    "alt": "Samsung - 50\" Class - LED - NU6900 Series - 2160p - Smart - 4K UHD TV with HDR, , hi-res",
    "_type": "media_file",
    "abs_url": "<my image location in site>",
    "title": "Samsung - 50\" Class - LED - NU6900 Series - 2160p - Smart - 4K UHD TV with HDR, ",
    "dis_base_url": "<my image location in site>"
   }],
   "_type": "image_group",
   "view_type": "hi-res"
  }
 ]
```